# React app production with Apache on Alwaysdata

Tags: reactjs, webserver, production

I have an app ReactJS in production mode on my apache web server, but I load it in user program (Only react), we can see source code.

I can use Apache but when I do, it override all other site on the same domain (*.example.com) with that conf:

```
DocumentRoot /home/neko/www/react/build
<Directory "/home/neko/www/react/build">
    RewriteEngine on
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
  </Directory>
```

Edit: On alwaysdata we doesn't need to set virtualhost braquet
So that config work but we can see source code anyway

Comment: What is the question you want answered?

Comment: How to configure apache with reactjs with the result that we cannot see source code of it

Comment: In Which folder is your source code kept?

Comment: I have resolve my problem myself, the build that we obtain with `react-scripts build` allow anyone to see source code as I see it. I build now with webpack, it give me just a main.js and index.html, the source code is safe with that. (In my question, I say source code as the possibility of see all code perfectly, with all modules and other things while the build folder on the server was not contains that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use [Webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack), that [tutoriel](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/) help me a lot.

At final, webpack create us a folder named `dist` with just `index.html` and `main.js` and that can be use like that on my web server. 
So it can be like that (On Alwaysdata):

```
DocumentRoot /home/neko/www/react/dist
<Directory "/home/neko/www/react/dist">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
  </Directory>
```